# Canvas Drawing conversion to DWG/DXF

Tags: android, kotlin, android-canvas, dxf, dwg

I am a newbie to working with Canvas in Android.
I am looking for a solution to convert lines from a Canvas to a DWG/DXF file formats.
What would you suggest? Unfortunately, I didn't find any related thread.

Thank you!

Comment: The DXF format is available online at https://images.autodesk.com/adsk/files/autocad_2012_pdf_dxf-reference_enu.pdf so you can write code to read that and work out what lines you need to draw on a canvas.